# How to prevent overlapping with arc4random_uniform

Tags: arc4random

I am making a simple game and I have four objects that move across the screen simultaneously (two objects move to the left, and two to the right). The X axis is a fixed point and does not need to change.

Using arc4random_uniform, sometimes the two objects are overlapping, i.e The objects have generated in their random position, but two of them are very close and overlap each other as they move across the screen.

I want to be able to set a gap so that the objects have a gap of 25px (y axis) minimum so they do not overlap each other as they move across the screen. What sort of code do I use to do this?

This is my code:

```
- (void)GenerateSpikes {

    CGRect frame = SpikeLeft.superview.bounds;
    CGFloat leftMargin = 5; //use whatever values you want for magins
    CGFloat rightMargin = 5;
    CGFloat topMargin = 80;
    CGFloat bottomMargin = 80;
    CGFloat randomX, randomY;

    randomX = arc4random_uniform(0) + 330 + rightMargin; // (330) Where they appear on screen on the Y Axis
    CGFloat SpikeLeftyMax = frame.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin-
    SpikeLeft.bounds.size.height/2;
    randomY = arc4random_uniform(SpikeLeftyMax) + topMargin;
    SpikeLeft.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);

    randomX = arc4random_uniform(0) + 10 + leftMargin;
    CGFloat SpikeRightyMax = frame.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin-
    SpikeRight.bounds.size.height/2;
    randomY = arc4random_uniform(SpikeRightyMax) + topMargin;
    SpikeRight.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);

    randomX = arc4random_uniform(0) + 10 + leftMargin;
    CGFloat SpikeRightOneyMax = frame.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin-
    SpikeRightOne.bounds.size.height/2;
    randomY = arc4random_uniform(SpikeRightOneyMax) + topMargin;
    SpikeRightOne.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);

    randomX = arc4random_uniform(0) + 200 + leftMargin;
    CGFloat SpikeLeftOneyMax = frame.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin-
    SpikeLeftOne.bounds.size.height/2;
    randomY = arc4random_uniform(SpikeLeftOneyMax) + topMargin;
    SpikeLeftOne.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);
}

- (void)ReverseSpikesMoving {

    SpikeLeft.center = CGPointMake(SpikeLeft.center.x -1, SpikeLeft.center.y);
    SpikeRight.center = CGPointMake(SpikeRight.center.x +1, SpikeRight.center.y);
    SpikeLeftOne.center = CGPointMake(SpikeLeftOne.center.x -1, SpikeLeftOne.center.y);
    SpikeRightOne.center = CGPointMake(SpikeRightOne.center.x +1, SpikeRightOne.center.y);


    if (SpikeRight.center.x > 330) { //Change to SpikeLeft and 16 <
        [ReverseSpikesMoving invalidate];
        [self GenerateSpikes];
        [self SpikeMovingTimer];
        [self ScoreNormal];

    }

    if (TimerCountdown < 0) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, TopTunnel.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, BottomTunnel.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, SpikeLeft.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, SpikeRight.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, SpikeLeftOne.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, SpikeRightOne.frame)) {
        [self GameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(SpikeLeft.frame, X2Score.frame)) {
        [self HideX2];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(SpikeLeftOne.frame, X2Score.frame)) {
        [self HideX2];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(SpikeRight.frame, X2Score.frame)) {
        [self HideX2];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(SpikeRightOne.frame, X2Score.frame)) {
        [self HideX2];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Face.frame, X2Score.frame)) {
        [self ScoreX2];
        [self HideX2];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to iterate and check for overlap when generating the random axis values...

Comment: What code do you use to check the axis values when they are generating?